# How to save a copy (a new version of each entity) of this tree like structure in TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Good day!

I have the data structure on the diagram below in a PostrgreSQL database. Backend is NestJS with TypeORM. I have to read the data, modify some props of the entities on the frontend, then write the same structure back in the DB as a new version, essentially, copying the entire stucture into new rows of the same table. Some of the 1st level child entities reference the same 2nd level child. This creates the following behaviour.
When I read the data into a JS object, I get it like this:

```
{questionGroup(id1): {
   question(id1): {
       answerGroup(id1): {
           answerOption(id1)
           answerOption(id2)
       }
   }
   question(id2): {
       answerGroup1(id1): {
           answerOption(id1)
           answerOption(id2)
       }
   question(id3): {
       answerGroup(id2): {
           answerOption(id3)
           answerOption(id4)
       }
   }
}
```

When I manually incremented their ID to keep the same structure, after writing back to the DB, some data didn't get written when using TypeORM's .save( ) method with the top level entity questionGroup.
When I deleted their ID to let the system sort it out, all the answerGroups and answerOptions got written back as many times as they were referenced by a question. I'm really lost on how to handle this kind of data structure's versioning, open to solutions. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First look:
Create tables for all yours unique fields, they are contains only ID. But the main table is the nastiest field **answerOption**.

**Create regular tables:**

- questionGroup
- question
- answerGroup
- answerOption

**Create main table:**

```js
answerOption: {
 questionGroup: id,
 question: id,
 answerGroup: id,
 answerOption: id,
}
```

Better solution is use manyToOne and OneToMany options for TypeORM